# Automatic vertical aligning of rows in the bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, html, css, ejs, bootstrap-5

I am doing in my private project table that completes through data from the database. I want rows to render vertically under headings (screenshot at the bottom of the question). I tried most of the solutions to that kind of question, but they don't work. Maybe I have sth wrong in the logic. Can you please help me find the solution?

EJS:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <% groups.forEach((group) => { %>
                                            <th><%= group.name %></th>
                                        <% }) %>
                                    </tr>
                                    
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <% groups.forEach((group) => { %>
                                        <tr>
                                            <% group.items.forEach((item) => { %>
                                                <% if(item.name === group.overseer.name){ %>
                                                    <td><strong><%= item.name %></strong></td>
                                                <% } else { %>
                                                    <td><%= item.name %></td>
                                                <% } %>
                                                
                                            <% }) %>
                                        </tr>
                                        
                                        
                                    <% }) %>
                                </tbody>
                    
                            </table>
```

How it looks like
[image: how it looks like]

How I want it to and it should look like
[image: it should be like here]

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/crazydeveloper09/pen/KKbLzXQ)

Answer (score 0):

It should look like something like this:

```
    <% for(let i=0; i<=groups[i]?.items?.length; i++) { %>
            <tr>
               <% groups.forEach((group, j) => { %>
                    <td><%= groups[j]?.items[i]?.name %></td>
               <% }) %>
            </tr> 
    <% } %>
```

You are left with adjusting conditions that you need, but this should display data the way you want.

Comment: You can try something like this: `<% const maxItems = Math.max(...groups.map(group => group.items.length)); %>
<% for(let i = 0; i < maxItems; i++) { %>
      <tr>
        <% groups.forEach((group, j) => { %>
          <td>
          <%if (groups[j].items[i]) {%>
            <%= groups[j].items[i].name %>
          <%}%>
          </td>
        <% }) %>
      </tr>
<%}%>`